# What is the best way to instantiate objects within classes, using dependency injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies, service-locator

I'm diving into the world of dependency injection and I'm running into a problem. The situation is as follows:

I have an `ImageGenerator` that generates images for certain situations. Into this `ImageGenerator` I 'constructor inject' several strings (filePaths) and a `Translator` class. Right now I do this using a dependency container that instantiates the `ImageGenerator` and `Translator`. So far so good.

Inside the ImageGenerator I now have hardcoded `new Imagick(...)` at several places. I'm looking for a way to inject these dependencies as well, so I can switch to a different image class in the future. For this I created an abstraction using 2 classes: `ImagickImage` and `GDImage` that both implement a set of methods defined in `ImageInterface`.

The problem is, how do I get instances of the correct `ImageInterface` inside the `ImageGenerator`? I've come up with a few options, but neither of them feel correct.

Can anyone enlighten me?

---

#### Option #1, use an ImageFactory class

I can inject into `ImageGenerator` an object that implements the `ImageFactory` interface. The `ImageFactory` interface has a method `instantiate($filePath)` that returns a new instance of `ImageInterface`. Problem is that I end up with a *lot* of classes and interfaces this way:

`ImageInterface`, `ImagickImage`, `GDImage`, `ImageFactoryInterface`, `ImagickImageFactory`, `GDImageFactory`.

#### Option #2, use a static factory method in the ImageInterface

Since the factory's `instantiate` methods will be just one line, I thought I could add a static `instantiate` method to the `ImageInterface` class. Then I can just inject an instance of `ImageInterface` into the ImageGenerator and that will function as the factory to create new instances.

#### Option #3, Inject the class name of the image

I could also inject the class name of the image class (either `ImagickImage` or `GDImage`) into the `ImageGenerator` class. Then I can just create new instances based on that class name.

#### Option #4

?

Comment: I'd go with option 1, because you wouldn't need to write a `GDImage` and `GDImageFactory` unless you decide to move away from Imagick. So you wouldn't add a lot of classes, only `ImageFactory` and `ImagickImageFactory`.

Comment: Good point, I only need the factory once I move to GD. However, it feels a little overkill to create an interface and class that just does: `return new ImagickImage($filePath);`. I'm leaning towards option 3 now. It's simple, virtually no overhead. The downside is that is not that obvious, there is no interface to indicate the intent.

Comment: I agree with @MatthieuNapoli. The slight class bloat is a better option than hardcoding instantiation logic into `ImageGenerator`. Also, your DI framework might already have a solution. For example, if you're using Guice, you could just inject a `Provider<ImageInterface>` or even an automatically generated factory implementation through assisted injection.

Comment: I use Slim Framework currently, which only offers a resource locator really. I've gone for factories now. However, that means I need at least 2 more files (interface+implementation) for each instantiable class.